# Configure m2e to ignore warnings in generated-sources folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a project which generates some code using Axis. This code is full of warnings (most of them, lack of generics), so, I usually just configure that source folder to ignore warnings.

Is there a way to do that using m2e or another maven plugin?

The advantage of that would show up when more people start using the project.

Comment: You can right-click the folder with the generated code, go to _Java Compiler_ and check _Ignore optional compile problems_. Unfortunately, when you run _Maven_ -> _Update project_, this property will be reset to default (I'd like to find a solution for this problem too; but if you don't update that project often, the setting may help).

Comment: Yeah... I realized that. I also want to share this with other developers that work in that project... so, right click won't work in this particular case.

Comment: Talking about Java (i dont know Axis) this would not be possible unless you somehow manage to have a `@suppressWarnings` generated inside each class - the best that Maven can do regarding the warnings is to show them on build ... e.g. have this in your compiler-Plugin entry `<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>` which is not what you are searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use AXIS but I had a similar problem when using JAXB for code generation. My solution was to annotate each class with @SuppressWarnings.

For JAXB I used the annox plugin. You can create a binding file that contains the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="YourSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">
    <jaxb:bindings multiple="true" node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType">
        <annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotateClass annox:class="java.lang.SuppressWarnings">
                <annox:annotate annox:field="value">all</annox:annotate>
            </annox:annotateClass>
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

so you do not have to touch your schema.